# Testing DisplayPort Alt Mode

Tags: graphics-card, display, displayport, thunderbolt, usb-c

**Is there an easy way to debug the DisplayPort Alt Mode of a recent Display?**

Background: I have a Dell P2415Q (first gen, with no 4K 60Hz support over HDMI) that has been causing issues with multiple hosts and various cables. Specifically, it seems one laptop was damaged after connecting it via USB-C DisplayPort Alt Mode. Another laptop, with a different cable into the same DP port in the display, has had similar issues. Both laptops were MacBook Pros of different generations. The resulting issues overlapped with known graphics issues with these devices. I haven't been able to (or willing to!) reproduce the issue with additional laptops, as they might get damaged.

As it is near impossible to define whether the display is the cause of the damage or whether the known graphics issues of the machines were to cause, I want to check the display before connecting it to any other devices as a *precautionary measure.*

**Do you know of any tools or debuggers (hardware or software to be installed on one of the older machines) that specifically debugs USB-C to Display Port via Alt Mode?**